# Copy contents of HTML to column- error handling VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Solved!!! I followed the advice of jbarker2160 `On Error Resume Next` was the solution.
I also refined my code which made it use less resources.

```
Sub Project()
Dim locationArr As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim g_strVar As String
Dim fake As String

 locationArr = Range("C1:C8877").Value

For i = LBound(locationArr) To UBound(locationArr)
    fake = (locationArr(i, 1))
     g_strVar = ImportTextFile(fake)
     ActiveCell.Value = g_strVar
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

    g_strVar = ""



Next i
End Sub

Function ImportTextFile(strFile As String) As String

On Error Resume Next
    Open strFile For Input As #1
    ImportTextFile = Input$(LOF(1), 1)
    Close #1

End Function
```

ORIGINAL QUESTION
How do I create an error handling on this process?
First time user.

I am copying my local backup file content from an intranet to a csv. I have been stumbling around VBA to build a solution. Now I need to figure out how to handle an error.

My current sheet contains a list of product SKU's, product names, and the file path for the html files that populate the pages (some of which are outdated paths).

Using VBA I have place the file paths into a single dimension array.
I have created a loop to go through the array open the file path, copy the contents of the file, close the file, and place the contents of the file into a cell.

How do I handle the corrupt/missing file paths?

```
Sub Project()
Dim locationArr As Variant
Dim Shex As Object
Dim i As Long
  Dim DataObj As New MSForms.DataObject
  Dim S As String
   '
   'access clipboard
  DataObj.GetFromClipboard
  S = DataObj.GetText
  '
  '
  ' create array
 locationArr = Range("C1:C8877").Value
 '
 '
 ' access file
 Set Shex = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
 '
 '
 '
 'loop array
For i = LBound(locationArr) To UBound(locationArr)
   '
   'open file
   Shex.Open (locationArr(i, 1))
   '
   ' give it time to open
   Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
   ' handle file
   Application.SendKeys ("^a")
   Application.SendKeys ("^c")
   Application.SendKeys ("%{F4}")
   ' give it time to close
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
   '
   'place clipboard into active cell
ActiveCell.Value = S
   '
   'move to new active cell
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
   '
   ' loop back
Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply put `On Error Resume Next` at the top of your code, but this can be dangerous in certain circumstances.

I don't foresee any problems adding it to this, but if you make any adjustments or additions to the code later you might want to reevaluate.

As it stands, the worst you can expect would be some missing data or a bunch of open files.

If the paths will never be valid again you can use an error handler to delete that path from your list.

Comment: This was the answer. Thank you for taking the time to look at it.